# how to store this type of color value 100, 1, 100, 200 in value folder

Tags: android

I am seting the background color of view like this ,Color.argb(100, 1, 100, 200). I want to store 100, 1, 100, 200 into values folder, how should i retrive it and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make an xml file called color.xml in layout folder.

then call it by the name like R.color.background

---

```
<resources> <color name="background">#333333</color> </resources>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

There is one strings.xml in value folder in res .

Now Stored your color code in it like below.

```
 <string name="first">100</string>
 <string name="second">1</string>
 <string name="third">100</string>
 <string name="fourth">200</string>
```

Now when ever you get this value you can get it using below.

```
String firstColor = getResources().getString(R.string.first);
```

after getting string value please convert it into integer using Integer.parseInt(firstColor) and pass it when ever you required...

Comment: Integer.parseint(String); in order to get the int from the String.

Answer (score 1):

XML file saved at `res/values/integers.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<integer-array name="bits">
        <item>100</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>100</item>
        <item>200</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves the integer array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int[] bits = res.getIntArray(R.array.bits);
```

And finally,

```
Color.argb(bits[0], bits[1], bits[2], bits[3]);
```

Of course, this is way more cumbersome than storing it in the `#` format as Bhavin2887 suggested.

Ref: [Integer Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray)